# R - sf package - is it possible to create a zoomed-in map on top of a larger map with some additional features?

Tags: r, maps

I would like to use the `sf` package to create a map of Europe and on top of it overlay a smaller, zoomed-in part of Europe. An example of how I would like my map to look like is pasted from Wikipedia here:

[image]

So, I know that I could first create a map of Europe, then separately a map of the zoomed-in region, and then probably use `ggdraw` to overlay them. However, specifically what I am interested in is how to create the red-shaded region which connects two rectangles (see image above). I was hoping that there is some method where this could be done automatically, but if you have any other workarounds, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Hello, can you provide a reproducible example of a map as well as the coordinates of the zoomed-in area? It will be easier to help you if we can start from an example

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to provide a map since it's in a geojson file which I can't upload here

Comment: An example doesn't have to be with your real data. The point is just to provide some code that creates a map and that everyone can run. Then, explain what you want to do (in your case, zoom on a part of the map). You can start from the examples in [`geom_sf()`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggsf.html)

Comment: Please have a look on: https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/adv-map.html - `grid::viewport()` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 2024-02-16:** at the time of writing there's a new feature in `geom_magnify()` to fill the area between the target and the zoomed-in plot (`proj.fill`). This is only available on the Github version so far, but might be available on CRAN when you read this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.2, GDAL 3.7.2, PROJ 9.3.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(rnaturalearth)
library(ggmagnify)

europe <- ne_countries(continent = "Europe", scale = 'medium',
                       type = 'map_units', returnclass = 'sf') 

your_map <- ggplot(europe) +
  geom_sf() +
  xlim(c(-20, 50)) +
  ylim(c(35, 70)) +
  theme_linedraw()

your_map + 
  geom_magnify(
    from = c(9, 15, 42, 45),
    to = c(22, 36, 46, 52),
    colour = "red",
    linewidth = 1,
    proj.fill = alpha("red", 0.5)
  )
```

[image]

---

**Original answer:**

You might be interested in the new [`ggmagnify`](https://github.com/hughjonesd/ggmagnify) package, but I'm not sure it allows to fill what corresponds to your red-shaded area (yet):

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.2, GDAL 3.6.2, PROJ 9.2.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(rnaturalearth)
library(ggmagnify)

europe <- ne_countries(continent = "Europe", scale = 'medium',
                       type = 'map_units', returnclass = 'sf') 

your_map <- ggplot(europe) +
  geom_sf() +
  xlim(c(-20, 50)) +
  ylim(c(35, 70)) +
  theme_linedraw()

ggm <- your_map + 
  geom_magnify(
    from = c(9, 15, 42, 45),
    to = c(22, 36, 46, 52), 
    linewidth = 1, shadow = TRUE,
    colour = "red"
  ) 

ggm
```

[image]

Comment: You could file a ggmagnify enhancement request... (author here)